# vim: how do I view my history of yanks and deletions?

Tags: vim, text-editors, buffer

`:buffers` displays a list of window buffers, but suppose I `dd`'d a few lines (this puts them in buffers 1-9) and yanked `"[a-z]yy` a few others. That's up to 35 buffers I couldn't possibly keep in my head.

How do I see a list of all of my deleted and yanked buffers?

(also: is is there a different name for both kinds of buffers? it seems confusing to call two completely separate feature "buffers")

**edit:** the confusion arose because, for some reason, the vim tutorial I was reading calls registers "named buffers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0-9` and `a-z` are [registers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers). You can get more information about them with [`:help registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers).

You can see the contents of all of them by entering [`:reg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:registers).

Comment: Also, the term `buffer` is explained in `:help windows-intro` and `:help 22.4`.

Comment: Interesting, O'Reilly's *Vi and Vim* calls them "Named Buffers"... with no reference to the term registers. Hence my confusion, as I had used that book for reference. Thanks.

Comment: @NoamGagliardi That book is mediocre at best (not the norm for O'Reilly). I highly recommend [Practical Vim](http://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim).